# Getting index and size of collection when using the map function

Tags: dictionary, clojure, functional-programming, mapreduce

I have this scenario. I use the map function in Clojure to apply a custom function on a collection. This function takes a while to execute and my collection is pretty large. I would like to be able to print something like this during each call of my function:

```
"Doing some stuff... (index/total)"
```

where index is the current element in the collection and total is the size. Is there a way to do this easily in clojure? I could send the size as a parameter to my collection. Also, I could, probably, use some kind of counter, but I was wondering if there was something built-in...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user=> (map-indexed (fn [idx itm] [idx itm]) "foobar")
([0 \f] [1 \o] [2 \o] [3 \b] [4 \a] [5 \r])
```

[map-indexed](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map-indexed)

```
(defn sebi [collection]
   (map-indexed #(println (format "Doing some stuff with %s (%d/%d)" 
                                  %2 (inc %1) (count collection)))
                collection))

(sebi ["Mary" "had" "a" "little" "lamb"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may pass lazy counter and sequence of size into map with collection.

```
(defn sebi [collection]
  (map #(println (format "Doing some staff with %s (%d/%d)" %1 (inc %2) %3))
       collection
       (range)
       (repeat (count collection)))

(sebi ["Mary" "had" "a" "little" "lamb"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work, but you might wan to modify them so the total is only calculated once (i.e. use a "(let [cnt (count collection)]...). Or you could look at [clj-progress](https://github.com/Intervox/clj-progress) which is a full featured progress reporting lib.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn map-reporting
  [msg f coll]
  (let [c (count coll)]
    (doall (map-indexed (fn [e i]
                          (println msg (str "[" (inc i) "/" c "]"))
                          (f e)) coll))))

user> (map-reporting "Doing some stuff" inc (range 5))
Doing some stuff [1/5]
Doing some stuff [2/5]
Doing some stuff [3/5]
Doing some stuff [4/5]
Doing some stuff [5/5]
(1 2 3 4 5)
```